# React, React-Redux Toolkit: Data not updating (beginners question)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

as I mentioned in my previous question, I'm kinda new to react & react-redux-toolkit, so the following question might sound a bit easy to some of you. My SPA is quite easy: I have a postform and a table below with the containing data. All I want to receive is to update the table whenever a new request has been posted to the db.

**addressSlice.js:**

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/address/';

const initialState = {
    address: [],
    status: 'idle', // 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
    error: null
}

export const fetchAddress = createAsyncThunk('api/address', async (address, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(BASE_URL);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
});

export const postAddress = createAsyncThunk('api/address', async (address, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(BASE_URL, address);
        return response.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return rejectWithValue(err.response.data);
    }
});

const addressSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'address',
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchAddress.pending, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'loading';
            })
            .addCase(fetchAddress.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
               state.address = action.payload;
                state.status = 'succeeded';
            })
            .addCase(fetchAddress.rejected, (state, action) => {
                state.status = 'failed';
                state.error = action.error.message;
            })
    }
});

export const selectAllAddress = (state) => state.address;

export default addressSlice.reducer
```

**AddressCreate.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { postAddress } from '../features/addressSlice';

const AddressCreate = () => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();

const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
const [mail, setMail] = useState('');
const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
const [addRequestStatus, setAddRequestState] = useState('idle');

const onFirstNameChanged = (e) => setFirstName(e.target.value);
const onLastNameChanged = (e) => setLastName(e.target.value);
const onMailChanged = (e) => setMail(e.target.value);
const onCountryChanged = (e) => setCountry(e.target.value);

const canSave = [firstName, lastName, mail, country].every(Boolean) && addRequestStatus === 'idle';

    const onSaveClicked = () => {
        if (canSave) {
            try {
                setAddRequestState('loading');

                dispatch(postAddress({
                    first_name: firstName,
                    last_name: lastName,
                    email: mail,
                    country: country,
                    slug: ''
                })).unwrap();

                setFirstName('');
                setLastName('');
                setMail('');
                setCountry('');
                setFirstName('');
                setAddRequestState('succeeded');
            } catch (err) {
                setAddRequestState('failed');
                console.log('Failed to add new address!', err);
            } finally {
                setAddRequestState('idle');
            };
        };
    };

    return(
        <section>
            <h2>Create new address:</h2>
            <form>
                <CustomInput placeholder="First name..." value={firstName} onChange={onFirstNameChanged} />
                <CustomInput placeholder="Last name..." value={lastName} onChange={onLastNameChanged} />
                <CustomInput placeholder="Email..." value={mail} onChange={onMailChanged} />
                <CustomInput placeholder="Country..." value={country} onChange={onCountryChanged} />
                <Stack sx={{ my: "1rem" }} spacing={2} direction="row">
                    <Button variant="contained" onClick={onSaveClicked} disabled={!canSave} >Create address...</Button>
                </Stack>
            </form>
        </section>
    )
};

export default AddressCreate;
```

**AddressTable.js:**

```
import * as React from 'react';

const AddressTable = ({ address }) => {
    return(
        <TableContainer sx={{ mx: 'auto', mt: '3rem', maxWidth: '75%' }} component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="simple table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left">Email</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="left">Country</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    { address.address && address.address.map((item) => (
                        <TableRow key={item.id} sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.full_name}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.email}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell component="th" scope="row">{item.country}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    )) }
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    )    
};

export default AddressTable;
```

**AddressList.js:**

```
import AddressTable from "../components/AddressTable";
import AddressCreate from '../components/AddressCreate';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchAddress, selectAllAddress, clearAdresses } from "./addressSlice";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const AddressList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const address = useSelector(selectAllAddress);    

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchAddress());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return(
        <>
            <AddressCreate />
            <AddressTable address={ address } />
        </>
    )
};

export default AddressList;
```

As you can see, the application is quit simple, and when entering the site everything get's displayed correct. But whenever I'm posting new data I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: address.address.map is not a function
```

But as soon as I press F5 or switch sites via navigation, the new data get's displayed as well. Can someone tell me what I am missing here? Or am I doing something fundamently wrong?
And this is what the data looks printed out in console:

```
{address: Array(1), status: 'succeeded', error: null}
    address: Array(1)
        0: {id: 14, first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe', full_name: 'John Doe', email: 'john.doe@email.com', …}
        length: 1
        [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    error: null
    status: "succeeded"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: Try to access address like this:  const { address } = useSelector(selectAllAddress);

Comment: @KarimAli unfortunately still no change in the error behaviour